# React - Django webpack config with dynamic 'output'

Tags: python, django, node.js, reactjs, webpack

**Have:**

I have a Django app. It has react for front-end. I have 2 django apps. `movies_list` and `series_list`. I have all my .jsx files inside `baseapplication/movies_list/interfaces/` and `baseapplication/series_list/interfaces/`. The entry point of 2 apps is given `...../index` as given in `entry` object of `web-pack.config.js` .

**Need:**

I need to put my compiled `.js` files inside `baseapplication/movies_list/static/movies_list` and `baseapplication/series_list/static/series_list`. So I need to find each entry in `entry` and get the abs path and construct my `output` path dynamically for the future apps. This will help my `python manage.py collectstatic` to get static files from each directory.

**How to configure the `output` to make it dynamic?**

```
module.exports = {

  //The base directory (absolute path) for resolving the entry option
    context: __dirname,

entry: {
  movies:  '../movies_list/interfaces/index',  
  series:  '../series_list/interfaces/index',
 },

output: {      
 // I need help here.
  path: path.join('<', "static"),
  //path: path.resolve('../[entry]/static/react_bundles/'), 
  filename: "[name].js",
},

}
```

https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set entry points to a full path of the resulting file. Something like this should work:

```
module.exports = {

  context: __dirname,

  entry: {
    'baseapplication/movies_list/static/movies_list/index':  '../movies_list/interfaces/index',
    'baseapplication/series_list/static/series_list/index':  '../series_list/interfaces/index',
   },

  output: {
    path: './',
    filename: "[name].js",
  },

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @lukasz. But the problem is my web-pack config is inside a directory called `baseapplication/react_support/web-pack.config.js`. So using `./` as path is setting full paths as entry points is actually creating  `baseapplication/react_support/baseapplication/movies_list/static/movies_list/index.js`. Instead, I wanted was `baseapplication/movies_list/static/movies_list/index.js` and I want it dynamic. So the `path` in `output` should somehow use the entry values.

Comment: Ok, I think I have got it. Thanks :)